# RSpec: Why does `instance_double` work with StandardError, but not other exception classes?

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec, mocking

In some tests, I want to setup a mock that raises a specific exception class. Because that particular exception is hard to instanciate in a test, I want to use a double.

Here's an example.

```rb
class SomeError < StandardError
  def initialize(some, random, params)
    # ...
  end
end

class SomeClass
  def some_method
    mocked_method
    :ok
  rescue SomeError
    :ko
  end

  def mocked_method
    true
  end
end

describe SomeClass do
  subject(:some_class) { described_class.new }

  describe '#some_method' do
    subject(:some_method) { some_class.some_method }

    it { is_expected.to be :ok }

    context 'when #mocked_method fails' do
      before do
        allow(some_class).to receive(:mocked_method)
          .and_raise(instance_double(SomeError))
      end

      it { is_expected.to be :ko }
    end
  end
end
```

However, running this test fails with the following message.

```
     Failure/Error:
       mocked_method

     TypeError:
       exception class/object expected
```

---

The weird part is that, if I replace `SomeError` with `StandardError`, it works just fine.

```rb
class SomeClass
  def some_method
    mocked_method
    :ok
  rescue StandardError
    :ko
  end

  def mocked_method
    true
  end
end

describe SomeClass do
  subject(:some_class) { described_class.new }

  describe '#some_method' do
    subject(:some_method) { some_class.some_method }

    it { is_expected.to be :ok }

    context 'when #mocked_method fails' do
      before do
        allow(some_class).to receive(:mocked_method)
          .and_raise(instance_double(StandardError))
      end

      it { is_expected.to be :ko }
    end
  end
end
```

---

**What is happening here? Is there some edge case when mocking `StandardError`? Alternatively, is there a better way to mock exception classes that are hard to instanciate?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue Explanation**

The `TypeError` is caused by [`Kernel#raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise).

`RSpec::Mocks::MessageExpectation#and_raise` wraps the call to `Kernel#raise` in a `Proc` (shown [Here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/d91621121b0857da907de7e8d7d0adce97022392/lib/rspec/mocks/message_expectation.rb#L186)) which is called later.

`Kernel#raise` accepts the following:

- No arguments - *"raises the exception in `$!` or raises a `RuntimeError` if `$!` is `nil`"*; or
- A String - *"raises a `RuntimeError` with the string as a message."*; or
- "*An `Exception` or another object that returns an `Exception` object when sent an `exception` message"* - this `Exception` will be raised

In your case `instance_double(SomeError)` is none of the above and therefor `Kernel#raise` throws a `TypeError`. The same can be reproduced with:

```
raise({a: 12})
in `raise': exception class/object expected (TypeError)
```

**Red Herring**

The reason `StandardError` works is not what you think.

Instead `StandardError` merely *appears* to work because `SomeClass#some_method` is rescuing `StandardError` and `TypeError` is a `StandardError` (inherits from `StandardError`). In this case the `TypeError` is still being raised it is just being rescued in the process.

You can prove this by changing `and_raise(instance_double(StandardError))` to `and_raise(instance_double(SomeError))` (or any other argument that does not adhere to the arguments accepted by `Kernel#raise`) and the code will still pass as long as `SomeClass#some_method` rescues `StandardError` or `TypeError`.

**Solution?**

While I don't fully understand the limitation you are under (e.g. *"that particular exception is hard to instanciate in a test"*), and would fully recommend just instantiating a `SomeError`, you could accomplish your goal  by simply creating an Exception that inherits from `SomeError` as a mock.

```
class SomeError < StandardError
  def initialize(some, random, params)
    # ...
  end
end

class MockSomeError < SomeError; def initialize(*);end; end  

class SomeClass
  def some_method
    mocked_method
    :ok
  rescue SomeError
    :ko
  end

  def mocked_method
    true
  end
end

describe SomeClass do
  subject(:some_class) { described_class.new }

  describe '#some_method' do
    subject(:some_method) { some_class.some_method }

    it { is_expected.to be :ok }

    context 'when #mocked_method fails' do
      before do
        allow(some_class).to receive(:mocked_method)
          .and_raise(MockSomeError)
      end

      it { is_expected.to be :ko }
    end
  end
end
```

[Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/MockException#spec.rb)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense! Interestingly enough, the solution you offer is exactly the workaround I came up with, albeit with an anonymous class defined in a `let` helper.

Comment: Just for further detail, the error class I'm trying to mock here is [`Gitlab::Error:ResponseError`](https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/error.rb#L15). Its constructor requires an `HTTParty::Response`, which in turn require an `HTTParty::Request` and a `Net::HTTPResponse`, which themselves require more arguments, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The `TypeError` message is actually coming from the `pry` gem. It checks that the raised error passes the check `exception.is_a?(Exception)`. Instance doubles will not  respond true to `is_a?` checks.

It's more common to raise an instance of the error with some values for the arguments:

```rb
before do
  allow(some_class).to receive(:mocked_method)
    .and_raise(SomeError.new(1, 'a', 'b'))
end
```

Comment: My project does not use `pry`. And, as stated in the question, the parameters required to instanciate the error are too hard to produce in a test environment.